# How do I install the latest version of STAN in R?

Tags: r, stan

I'm trying to get the latest version of STAN in R because of a particular command I want to use that is only available in STAN (the 'reverse' function: https://mc-stan.org/docs/functions-reference/reverse-functions.html). This command is only available in STAN 2.23 and over.

When I use the install.packages() command in R, it installs version 2.21.0.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the last update to the `rstan` project was in 2021, see https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/tree/develop/rstan/rstan, so the best you can do is what they have released, currently [2.21.8 on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rstan/index.html). I see no reason why you are not able to upgrade above 2.21.0, it could be due to many things we don't know about.

Comment: I found a thread on the STAN forums that explains why the version in R/hosted on CRAN is much further behind the latest version of STAN, seems like there's no recourse but to wait. Until then, I'll just try to code a 'reverse' function in the functions block instead.

https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/status-on-rstan-cran-and-latest-versions-of-stan/28293

Comment: From that discourse, you might try `remotes::install_github("stan-dev/rstan", ref = "experimental", subdir = "rstan/rstan")`. I don't use STAN and have not tested that, so caveat emptor ... but it appears to be on 2.31 instead of 2.21.8.